# Why doesn't Ajax calendar extender work until I click button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AjaxCalendarExtender applied on text box. It doesn't work until i click button within page (any asp button which doesn't post back). After clicking any button it starts working like a charm.

Why ?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxDateOfBirth" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="calExt1" runat="server" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtBoxDateOfBirth">
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowViewPersonalInfo" runat="server" OnClick="btnShowViewPersonalInfo_Click"/>
```

this button doesn't nothing big, just changes VIEWs in webform. Please help me I can't figure it out since man days.

Update: Code behind Button click event.

```
btnShowViewPersonalInfo.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#106e5b");
btnShowViewPersonalInfo.ForeColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
btnShowViewPersonalInfo.Font.Bold = true;

MultiviewHR.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
```

Nothing else, it just switches view.

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in the three lines you've posted. Post the code that the button executes.

Comment: @Houseman Ok sir, please check the updated question

Comment: Oh god, don't use the ajaxcontroltoolkit..! Worst idea microsoft ever had. I'm surprised it's still supported. I would recommend the [jquery ui datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) as a much better replacement

Comment: Sir, My project is very very large and contains many extender and it would take a lot of time to replace. So if you could fix the current issue ? Sir. @Liam

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?